# Migrating es5 to es6 export default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es5-shim

I am trying to migrate a code from es5 to es6, I am quite new in both, if someone could help me, I will be very thankful.

**es5 version:**

lib.js

```
module.exports = {
    foo1: function () { 
        this.foo2() {
           ... 
        }
    },
    foo2: function () { 
        ...
    }
}
```

main.js

```
const Lib = require("./lib");
Lib.foo1( { ... });
```

**es6 version - I am trying:**

lib.ts

```
export default { 
    foo1() {
        this.foo2(() => {
            ... 
        });                 
    },
    foo2(){ ... }
}
```

main.ts

```
import * as Lib from "./lib";
Lib.foo1({ ... })
```

The problem is in my main.ts foo1 can not be resolved.
Any idea or recommendation?

Thank!

Comment: Try `import Lib from "./lib";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be just

```
import Lib from "./lib";
```

Otherwise, if you use `* as` notation you could access `default` export with `Lib.default`, but this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the following part of your code:

```
foo1: function () { 
    this.foo2() {
       ... 
    }
}
```

That seems invalid.

Anyway, do not introduce your own pseudo-module like structure. It's not necessary. `lib.js` is already a module.

**lib.js**

```
export function foo1() {
    foo2();
}
export function foo2() { ... }
```

**main.js**

```
import {foo, foo2} from './lib';
```